# Unable to ping domain set up in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have multiple GoDaddy domains that point to AWS DNS Servers, which in turn point to a load balancer and thence to (at the moment) an instance.  All but one of these work fine and one steadfastly refuses to work, even after deleting and recreating (multiple times).

Using the SDK I have tried to find a significant difference between Zones / Resource Record Sets and have not come up with anything that would explain it.  DNSSTuff has not yielded any clues (nor have a couple of other online tools).

An example of a working domain is care.work, and the failing one is plaitapp.org.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It just appears to have been amazingly slow propogation for one domain, while all the others were almost instant.